# Summation formula for this?

Tags: summation, recursive-algorithms, bit-strings

I have found the following summation formula based on a recurrence. It supposes $n = 2^k$ where k is an integer. I've intuitively discovered that the following closed form may be true (following the constraint on n), but I'm not sure why.

$\sum_{\textstyle i=0}^{\textstyle \lg n}  {\frac n{2^i}}\\
= n\sum_{\textstyle i=0}^{\textstyle \lg n} \frac 1{2^i}\\
= n(1+ \frac 12 + \frac 14 +...+ \frac 1n)\\
= 2n-1\\$

I've reasoned that the last line should be true because if I plug in n=32 the solution is 63, and if we think about the numbers being added as $1$s in a long bit string, we will end up with lg$n+1$ ones in a row. I'm wondering if there is a summation formula or inductive proof that can show that this is true? I'm just waving my hands thinking this must be true, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Is lg the natural logarithm?

Comment: So you are interested in the sum $\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{2^k}{2^i}$?

Comment: Sorry, lg is $log_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of the formula $\sum_{i=0}^n x^i ={1-x^{n+1}\over 1-x}$. Here you have $x=1/2$.

Comment: Cool! I was thinking there must be some formula but I couldn't remember or my brain was fried... Thanks!

Comment: Formulas are easy to forget! I believe that this is called a geometric series/sum if you want to look it up

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be a nonnegative integer.  Then $$\sum_{i=0}^m \frac{1}{2^i}$$ is simply a finite geometric series with common ratio $r = 1/2$.  In general, $$\sum_{i=0}^m r^i = \begin{cases} \frac{r^{m+1} - 1}{r - 1}, & r \ne 1, \\ m+1, & r = 1, \end{cases} \tag{1}$$ from which your desired result follows immediately.

The proof of $(1)$ is straightforward and is typically discussed in high school algebra.  One sees that the summation is telescoping for $r \ne 1$:
$$(r - 1) \sum_{i=0}^m r^i = \sum_{i=0}^m r^{i+1} - r^i = \sum_{i=0}^m r^{i+1} - \sum_{i=0}^m r^i = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} r^i - \sum_{i=0}^m r^i = r^{m+1} - r^0 = r^{m+1} - 1.$$  And when $r = 1$, the summation is trivial.

Comment: awesome, yes I can see it now. Thank you!

Comment: @dover if you found this answer useful, please upvote and accept it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sum is $f(k) = 2^k \sum_{i=0}^k (\frac{1}{2})^i$:

$\sum_{i=0}^k (\frac{1}{2})^i = \frac{1-\frac{1}{2}^k}{\frac{1}{2}}$

It follows that this sum is
$$2^{k+1}(1-2^{-k}) = 2^{k+1}-2$$

Comment: Thank you for your response, another helpful way to look at it!